# python performing recursion on rows in df

Tags: python, pandas, recursion, rows

I want to perform the following calculations with my df. I've done this in Excel but I'm not sure how to do this using Python. Here's the calculation

```
      initial|  recursion begins
Name  | 1    | 2        | 3        | 4   ...
------------------------------------------------
A     | A1   | A2       | A3       | A4         <--given 
a     | a1=0 | a2=c1*A2 | a3=c2*A3 | a4=c3*A4   <--calculation (1st cell always = 0)
c     | c1=1 | c2=c1-a2 | c3=c2-a3 | c4=c3-a4   <--calculation (1st cell always 1)
```

Here's my example:

df

```
Name    1    2     3    4     5
----------------------------------
A       0   .125  .286  .25  .333
B       0   0     0    .5    -
```

the output would be:

```
Name    1    2     3     4    5
----------------------------------
A       0   .125  .286  .25  .333
Ax      0   .125  .25   .156 .156  
Ay      1   .875  .625  .469 .313
B       0   .1    0     .25    -
Bx      0   .1    0     .225   -
By      1   .9    .9    .675   -
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this is enough information to answer the question. There seems very little intuition behind the results generated here. Can you explain what it is you're trying to do and how you arrive at the result?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The logic that I used here is how I wrote the formula on excel.  My goal is to run the 2 recursion formulas on the given rows A and B.   The Ax, Ay and Bx, By are derived from the formulas in the first box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain a little bit .

`a2=c1*A2;c2=c1-a2, then c2=c1-a2=c1-c1*A2=c1(1-A2)`,

c3 should be `c3=c2(1-A3)=c1(1-A2)(1-A3)`, that is where`(1-df).cumprod(1)`, come from

```
df=df.set_index('Name') 
df1=(1-df).cumprod(1)
df2=df1.shift(1,axis=1).mul(df)

pd.concat([df,df1,df2],keys=['','x','y']).fillna({'1':0})


Out[769]: 
          1      2        3         4         5
  Name                                         
  A     0.0  0.125  0.28600  0.250000  0.333000
  B     0.0  0.000  0.00000  0.500000       NaN
x A     1.0  0.875  0.62475  0.468562  0.312531
  B     1.0  1.000  1.00000  0.500000       NaN
y A     0.0  0.125  0.25025  0.156187  0.156031
  B     0.0  0.000  0.00000  0.500000       NaN
```

Comment: you're right!  However when I run the 1st line, I get: TypeError: Could not operate 1 with block values unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @TylerNG seems like you have `str` rather than `numeric`, df=df.apply(pd.to_numeric)

Comment: I can't do that since the field Name is a string.  
('Unable to parse string "A" at position 0', 'occurred at index Name')

Comment: @TylerNG you can do , df=df.set_index('Name')

Comment: Wow it works! This is so different than excel.  Thanks again! you're awesome!

Comment: @TylerNG yw~ :-) happy coding